# Parse XML tag with multiple possible types [Rust, serde, serde-xml-rs]

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I want to parse an XML element that may contain different data types.

The following is the most simple case I could think of:

```rust
use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_xml_rs::{from_str};

const XML: &str = r#"
<element>
    foo
</element>
"#;
const XML2: &str = r#"
<element>
    123
</element>
"#;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Element {
    #[serde(rename="element")]
    Text(String),
    #[serde(rename="element")]
    Number(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let el: Element = from_str(&XML).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", &el);
    println!("\n\n\n\n");
    let el2: Element = from_str(&XML2).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", &el2);
}
```

The current code parses both elements as Text(String), instead of Text(String), Number(i32) respectively.

If I reverse the order the program crashes, because "foo" cannot be parsed as integer.

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Element {
    #[serde(rename="element")]
    Number(i32),
    #[serde(rename="element")]
    Text(String),
}
```

How can I correctly implement my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your post correctly, you want `Number` whenever the value can be parsed as a `i32` and `Text` otherwise. You can implement that using the `FromStr` trait.

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, serde_with::DeserializeFromStr, Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Element {
    #[serde(rename="element")]
    Text(String),
    #[serde(rename="element")]
    Number(i32),
}

impl std::str::FromStr for Element {
    type Err = std::convert::Infallible;
    
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        if let Ok(i) = s.parse::<i32>() {
            Ok(Element::Number(i))
        } else {
            Ok(Element::Text(s.to_string()))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do the same, when Number(i32) is a struct instead? E.g.: struct SubElement { id: i32 }

Comment: Do you mean having `Number(SubElement)` instead of `Number(i32)` in the enum definition? In that case you can return `Ok(Element::Number(SubElement{ id: i }))` in the `FromStr`.

Comment: No, I mean a `struct SubElement{ id: i32 }` that is defined outside the `enum`. So the options of the enum are either `Text(String)` or `SubElement`. `XML2` would be `<element><subelement id="123"></subelement></element>`.

Comment: Your `Element` enum then only has one variant, like `enum Element { Text(String) }`? You cannot return two different types from the same function. You will need to put them in a new enum, which has variants for `Element` and `SubElement`, or perform type erasure and return boxed values. If I misunderstand your problem, maybe start a new question.

Comment: I started a new question.